# Ionic splash screen sizes

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, splash-screen

I can't use `ionic cordova resources` command because I want a splash screen with a border on every device.

Which are the different file sizes needed for every device?

Answer (score 5):

**ANDROID:**

```
drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png       800x480
drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png       320x240
drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png       480x320
drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png      1280720
drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png     1600x960
drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png    1920x1280
drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png       480x800
drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png       240x320
drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png       320x480
drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png      720x1280
drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png     960x1600
drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png    1280x1920
```

**IOS:**

```
Default-568h@2x~iphone.png          640x1136
Default-667h.png                    750x1334
Default-736h.png                    1242x2208
Default-Landscape-736h.png          2208x1242
Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png      2732x2048
Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png       2048x1536
Default-Landscape~ipad.png          1024x768
Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png       2048x2732
Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png        1536x2048
Default-Portrait~ipad.png           768x1024
Default@2x~iphone.png               640x960
Default~iphone.png                  320x480
```